# Notice: Undefined index with PHP session

Tags: php, session

I have my index.php page, which is where users can register and log in with sessions.

This is the error I'm getting:

> Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\wamp\www\CMS\admin\index.php on line 18.

What's wrong with my code?

Short snippet of `index.php`:

**Source code**:

```
<?php include "includes/admin_header.php" ?>

<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <?php include "includes/admin_navigation.php" ?>

    <div id="page-wrapper">

        <div class="container-fluid">

            <!-- Page Heading -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1 class="page-header">
                        Welcome To Admin

                        <small><?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?></small>
                    </h1>

                </div>
            </div>
```

This is my login.php

**Source code**:

```
<?php include "db.php"; ?>
<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php

    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        // For login security
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $username);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $password);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '{$username}' ";
        $select_user_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        if(!$select_user_query){

            die("QUERY FAILED: " . mysqli_error($connection));
        }

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_user_query)) {

            $db_user_id = $row['user_id'];
            $db_username = $row['username'];
            $db_user_password = $row['user_password'];
            $db_user_firstname = $row['user_firstname'];
            $db_user_lastname = $row['user_lastname'];
            $db_user_role = $row['user_role'];
        }

        if ($username !== $db_username && $password !== $db_user_password) {

            header("Location: ../index.php");

        } else if($username === $db_username &&
                  $password === $db_user_password) {

            $_SESSION['username'] = $db_username;
            $_SESSION['firstname'] = $db_user_firstname;
            $_SESSION['lastname'] = $db_user_lastname;
            $_SESSION['user_role'] = $db_user_role;

            header("Location: ../admin");
        }
        else {
            header("Location: ../index.php");
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Check whether the session is set or not before echoing `if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){ echo $_SESSION['username']; }`

Comment: Is `session_start()` called? Does the index really exist? What do you see when you do `var_dump($_SESSION)`?

Comment: did you call session_start() at the very beginning of your file ?

Comment: Check if the session is set, if it is then dump it to the screen and see what's in the array.

You can then start debugging from there.

Answer (score 4):

On the first line of your PHP script, write this:

```
if (session_status !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
    session_start();
}
```

For debugging purposes, add

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

after the **if { }** block. You also have to be sure that the session exists in every file you want to use it. To simplify the process I'll give you a short example:

1. You create a header.php file where you put the if {} block from above.
2. Whenever you want to use the session in a script, you just include that header file on the first line of your script.

   //header.php
   if (session_status !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
       session_start();
   }

   //index.php
   include 'header.php';
   echo $_SESSION['username'];

   //login.php
   include 'header.php';
   $_SESSION['username'] = 'John Doe';